# Configure Data Source in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, datasource, hikaricp

I have a spring boot application,

Presently using this configuration for Data source

```
@PropertySource("file:D:\\Spring Workspace\\test\\dbconfig.properties")
public class DataSourceConfig {
    @Value("db_driverClassName")
    private String className;
    @Value("db_url")
    private String url;
    @Value("db_username")
    private String username;
    @Value("db_userpassword")
    private String password;
    
    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(className);
        dataSourceBuilder.url(url);
        dataSourceBuilder.username(username);
        dataSourceBuilder.password(password);
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

dbconfig.properties file

```
db_driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
db_url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testDB"
db_username="postgres"
db_userpassword="password"
```

**EXCEPTION**

```
2021-07-15 12:34:21.400 ERROR 5352 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : Failed to load driver class db_driverClassName from HikariConfig class classloader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@368239c8
2021-07-15 12:34:21.403  WARN 5352 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getDataSource' defined in class path resource [com/myapp/quartz/config/DataSourceConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'getDataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load driver class db_driverClassName in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
2021-07-15 12:34:21.405  INFO 5352 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-07-15 12:34:21.418  INFO 5352 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-07-15 12:34:21.437 ERROR 5352 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getDataSource' defined in class path resource [com/myapp/quartz/config/DataSourceConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'getDataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load driver class db_driverClassName in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at com.myapp.quartz.GatewayApplication.main(GatewayApplication.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
```

I tried by setting up the values manually instead of placing it into a file, that was working, But when I tried to fetch the properties values from a file, I was getting this exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove quotes sign from properties values

```
db_driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
db_url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testDB
db_username=postgres
db_userpassword=password
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @user7294900, it started working

Answer (score 0):

use the relative path instead of the absolute path here

```
@PropertySource("file:D:\\Spring Workspace\\test\\dbconfig.properties")
```

and remove double quotes in `dbconfig.properties file`

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add one more point to the answer, after putting up the solution got from @user7294900, Still I faced an issue because of it, Finally Resolved

The mapping of the values from properties file, I was using wrong syntax

**@Value("db_driverClassName")**

changed to

**@Value("${db_driverClassName}")**